# Recursive Search Function Java

Tags: java, recursion

```
public int search(String type) {
  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (array[size-1-i].contains(type)) return i;
  }
  return -1;
}
```

I am having trouble doing a recursive function of this previous search function , can somebody help me ?

Comment: Where is recursion here?

Comment: What did you try before asking?

Comment: Probably you are confused between recursion and iteration. You can take a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21194/Iterative-vs-Recursive-Approaches)

Comment: theres is no recursion in this one ,  this is the function that is given in an exercise and they ask to do this but in a recursive way

Answer (score 0):

For a recursive function, a simple solution would be to pass in the value you want to search and the index to search at as parameters to the function.

Then you check

1. if the index passed in is greater than length of array , then return -1 (since we were not able to find the element.
2. if you can find the value pass in at the index passed in, if yes, just return that index ,
3. if not above 2 , then try to search it at next index.

For this recursive function, start at index  0 , by passing 0 when calling the function.

Example code -

```
public int search(String type, int index) {
  if (index >= array.length) {
    return -1;
  }
  else if(array[index].contains(type)) {
    return array.length - i + 1; # assuming size from your function is array.length
  }
  else {
    return search(type, index + 1)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to write a recursive variant of this search function.  **I am not doing any optimization in your code as you need to take care of that**. I have assumed few things to make your code compile and here is the code I have tried:

```
    static String[] array = new String[] {"John", "Sam", "David"};
    static int size = array.length;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int index = searchRecursive(0,"Sam");
        System.out.println("Index: " + index);
    }

    public static int searchRecursive(int indexToCheck, String type) {
            int result = -1;
            if(indexToCheck<size) {
                if(array[size-1-indexToCheck].contains(type)) {
                    result = indexToCheck;
                } else {
                    result = searchRecursive(indexToCheck+1,type);
                }
            }
            return result;
    }

    public static int searchIterative(String type) {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            if (array[size-1-i].contains(type)) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```